# Jubula fails to start my application

Tags: java, gui-testing, jubula

I'm in the process of evaluating various GUI test frameworks.

I started with Jubula, basically following this tuturial: http://jmhofer.johoop.de/?p=132 but applying it to our application.

I have a batch file which starts our applciation, but I can't start it through Jubula.

As described here http://jmhofer.johoop.de/?p=163 I start the AUT Agent and connect to it, but when I try to start the application via "Start AUT" nothing happens. Nothing in the Jubula Console, nothing in the "Start AUT Agent" Window.

What might be the reason for this? Where can I look for more information what is going wrong?

Comment: it does work now, although haven't change anything I know about ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that I always clicked on the run button (what a stupid idea).

You have to actually have to use the drop down part of the button to select you AUT at least once.